# angularjs delay route change upon click as long new background image does not load

Tags: css, angularjs

My web app shows body background for a second then it loads the dynamic background when i route from one page to another. I am trying to remove that white flash by adding a splash screen using AngularJS. I looked at some tutorials but were not able to find exact solution.
how do i avoid showing the white body background before my div background loads?
any suggestions?

HTML

```
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse"> 
     <div class="wrapper"  ng-style="{'background': backgroundImg}" >
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content">
          <div ng-view></div>
        </section>
      </div>
     </body>
```

my route

```
$routeProvider.when('/about',{
    templateUrl:'partials/about.php',
    controller: 'pageController'
});
```

My controller

```
app.controller("pageController",function($scope, $rootScope){
$scope.title = "About Us";
$rootScope.backgroundImg="url('http://abounde.com/uploads/images/abt-min.jpg')";   //abt bg
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
   console.log("about page loaded");
});
```

});

Comment: please add some piece of code explaining how you change route and how you dynamically load your background

Comment: @RonanQuillevere Please kindly look now. I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the pb is that when you route to another page then you launch a new request to download your background with your url(...). Because this request can take time then you have your white screen.

So a solution could be to "preload" all background images when you open your app. So before displaying anything on your app you can display a "loading..." div. In background download all your backgrounds.

Once this is done, when changing route then simply change the css class of your wrapper div to the css class containing the correct background image.

Answer (score 0):

On this particular page, you could have a div that wraps the entire document.

Give this div a class with css ie .document-wrapper-invisible

in your css give .display-none class a display property of none

```
.dislay-none {
display: none;
}
```

When your view content loaded function runs, remove this class. You can simply set a variable to be true and use ng-class to conditionally remove the class. ie

```
<div ng-class="{display-none: !documentLoaded}">
// your page content
</div>
```

in your controller

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
   console.log("about page loaded");
   $scope.documentLoaded = true;

});
```

Something along these lines should work (I've only ever used rootScope for the viewContentLoaded event, if $scope works on it's own then great)

Comment: @ceckendrode It does not work as I wants sir. Thanks for your try. I think a loading screen would be best solution however i have no idea how to implement it